# How to search a tag on visual studio

Tags: html, visual-studio

I would like to search the tag `_ngcontent-etf-c5` into a project, my problem is that there are more than 100 000 files.

Do you know a trick to find the file with the tag `_ngcontent-etf-c5` quickly?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of "trick" would you expect? If you don't have any additional information to narrow down your search, the only thing you can do is checking every single file if it contains the desired string ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use the search option available in Visual Studio. Just type the whatever tag name or string you are looking for in the search field and all the files where that tag or string has been used gets listed.

*Note - Here I've just presented the ss of VS Code, but similar options are there in Visual Studio as well.

[image]